# I can not install or remove apps After trying to install bumblebee and nvidia prime

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dpkg, bumblebee

Here are the details which terminal output when trying to remove or upgrade

I tried `autoremove - install configure dpkg` and nothings work for me

```
Removing nvidia-331 (331.89-0ubuntu1~xedgers14.04.2) ...
stop: Unknown instance: 
userdel: existing lock file /etc/subgid.lock without a PID
userdel: cannot lock /etc/subgid; try again later.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-331 (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 18
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-331
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f` and post the results here.

Comment: Same error massage I get after sudo apt-get install -f

Answer (score -1):

The solution in [post #4](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2204164&p=13020473#post13020473) of [How do I uninstall this program (jetty)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2204164) fixed this problem for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.